# The drool simulation

Tags: animation, fluid-simulation

Can you tell me how to make the drool simulation like here: https://youtu.be/gR2OhFLkLM0#t=5m6s?

Fluid simulation doesn't give sticky effect, it's just water. I tried to stretch mesh using softbody, but mesh just stretched out and practically didn't change its shape. In short, it turned out nonsense.

[image]

I have no more ideas how to do this.

Comment: Maybe you could try with bones, for example bendy bones + Stretch To constraint, at least you would have 100% control on it

Comment: Perhaps you can do this with the cloth simulation?

Comment: Yeah, with Cloth it looks better. But how to control the central part of mesh? I tried to add a bone to that place, but when start simulation, it doesn't affect the mesh. https://i.stack.imgur.com/x6YAW.gif